# Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHBITMAP memory leakage

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+

I call repeatedly this code getting a memory leakage:

```
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
int screen_height;
int screen_width;

CVCamStream::CVCamStream(HRESULT *phr, CVCam *pParent, LPCWSTR pPinName) : CSourceStream(LPCSTR(FILTER_NAME),phr, pParent, pPinName), m_pParent(pParent)
{
    hdc = GetDC(NULL);

    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
}

CVCamStream::~CVCamStream()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    DeleteDC(hdc);
} 

HRESULT CVCamStream::FillBuffer(IMediaSample *pms)
{
    REFERENCE_TIME rtNow;
    REFERENCE_TIME avgFrameTime = ((VIDEOINFOHEADER*)m_mt.pbFormat)->AvgTimePerFrame;

    static clock_t refClock = clock();
    double elapsed = (clock() - refClock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    rtNow = m_rtLastTime;
    m_rtLastTime += avgFrameTime;
    pms->SetTime(&rtNow, &m_rtLastTime);
    pms->SetSyncPoint(TRUE);

    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    CImage image;
    image.Create(screen_width, screen_height, 24);
    SelectObject(memdc, image);

    BYTE *pData;
    pms->GetPointer(&pData);
    long lDataLen = pms->GetSize();

    Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(screen_width, screen_height, PixelFormat24bppRGB);

    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteDC(memdc);

    // memdc is already deleted
    bitmap->FromHBITMAP(image, NULL);

    delete bitmap;
    image.Destroy();
    DeleteObject(image);
    DeleteDC(memdc);

    return NOERROR;
}
```

But every time the RAM usage increases. The offending line is the `FromHBITMAP()` function because commenting it there is no more leakage.

I know `FromHBITMAP()` creates a copy of the bitmap but I thought I free all the memories!

What's wrong here?

Comment: This code does not compile. `bitmap` type is wrong. If it is a pointer (guessed by `new` init) then you should delete it. Also there is no cleanup for  `hdc`.

Comment: Fixed the typo and updated the code: the memory leakage is still there.

Comment: Perhaps is there another way to capture the screen content in a GDi+ Bitmap?

Comment: It's a shame you deleted your question about the stepping motor, I thought it was interesting despite some disagreement from others. You might want to study [Jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) since this is what you were trying to minimize with the S-curve.

Comment: The question I'm talking about is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572073/s-shape-profile-real-time-algorithm. I should have left a link earlier.

Comment: I don't want to hurt anyone. Perhaps it's not the right place to ask here. Anyway, I found a possible solution dividing the profile in 7 parts and use a finite-state-machine to decide what's next.

Comment: DeleteObject() that returned from SelectObject()

Answer (score 1):

`FromHBITMAP` does not take ownership of the passed bitmap handle. You can just pass bitmap handle that will be still owned by `CImage` instance. Also [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536291(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Do not pass to the Bitmap::FromHBITMAP method a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context.

And you are calling it while `image` is still selected into `memdc`.

Comment: I have to use `memdc` for `BitBlt()`. I tried to delete it before calling `FromHBITMAP` and I also changed the `image.Detach()` to `image`. Same behavior.

Comment: The first thing that image is still selected into DC when it should not be. Is the code posed actually complete? You've added notes about destructor and constructor so I guess there are more code that is not shown here.

Comment: Please, look at the updated code. The "hidden" code was not related to the image handling.